# Grafana: Convert text box(Template Variable) to integer

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, grafana

I've created a dashboard in grafana which shows the average availability and utilization of a machine. I also want to include the moving average and I've been asked to enable the user to determine the interval of the moving averagein weeks.

In order to do this I would like to use a text box template variable and convert it  to an integer. The graphs are and the queries are grouped per days. The moving average is determined based on the average availability per day. Therefore, I would like to do this calculation on the template variable: `([[MA_interval]] * 7) - 1`

My code looks like this:

```
Select AVG(avgAvailability) OVER(ORDER by day ROWS BETWEEN [[MA_interval]] PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS "Moving Average of Availability"
```

I would like to do this calculation on the template variable: 
`([[MA_interval]] * 7) - 1`

Where `[[MA_interval]]` is the interval in weeks and 7 is the number of days in a week.

Could anyone help me out? I am using a MariaDB server as database.

Comment: Are you asking how to build a text box?  Or to debug the SQL?  Or to get the value entered into the text box copied to the SQL?

Comment: I am asking to get the value entered into the text box copied into the SQL, so that SQL can use it to calculate the actual interval value